# Adding variables with their values to a Java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

I want to add to a Java `JFrame` a list of my class's fields names, along with their respective values. Those fields can of course change value during the program's execution and i want this change to be displayed dynamically in my GUI. If for example i have a field `private int networkId;` in a class `BaseStation`, how can i make it appear in the frame of a class `BaseStationFrame`?

Comment: Have you wrote any code for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your UI to have access to private fields of your class, you won't have much options

- Use reflection to access those fields (not recommended)
- Make those fields public (not recommended either) or package visible and place all code in one package (not recommended either)
- Add decent getters and setters and fire `PropertyChangeEvent`s when those fields change.

Your UI can then use the getter to obtain the initial value, and use the events to update the UI when the value of a field has been changed. You could even write a fairly generic UI component for this by using reflection to obtain all the getters, but if it is only for a few classes this might be overkill

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% understanding the question, but would the [l2fprod PropertySheet](http://www.l2fprod.com/common/) do what you need if via JavaBeans?

Answer (score 1):

A common approach would be to access the methods from the component that allow you to manipulate the component values.

Here a simple example using a text area.

```
private final static String newline = "\n";
private JTextArea textArea;


public void init() {
   //Make sure your components are not null;
   textArea = new JTextArea();  
}   

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    String text = textArea.getText();
    textArea.append(textArea + newline);
}

//Get set methods
```

Depending on your needs and variable type, you might need to parse or use special methods.
I would recomend you to read the [documentation for the javax.swing package.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html)

Also in oracles site there is a great tutorial on [javax.swing GUI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)

Comment: I am not sure i completely understood your example above. How can i use this code to display a particular variable, e.g. `int x`?

Comment: @nikos for example you could have a JLabel and update it every time you type something in the text area. To be honest i dont really understand what do you really want. Is it maybe your problem that you dont see the changes take place? (See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179136/jtable-how-to-refresh-table-model-after-insert-delete-or-update-the-data)

Answer (score 1):

Well...you could store static final Strings that contain the names of your fields, and design some association between the String representation of the name of a field, and the value of that field.

Or, you could use a Map for all of your fields, defining key-value pairs for them. When you want to call the fields, you do a Map.get(), and when you want to print them, you could do something like

```
Set s = map.keySet()
for(Object o : s) {
    print(o.toString() + " = " + map.get(o).toString())
}
```

This is, of course, Sudocode to hopefully get the ball rolling for you

Good Luck :)