# JTable doesn't show new model after adding new row

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I can't repaint my jTable. I must re-run all application to show addRow.

This is the code:

MainPage.java http://pastebin.com/6FZL1pKC

```java
public class Mainpage2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public static DefaultTableModel tripModel;
/**
 * Creates new form carpoolingui
 */
public Mainpage2(){
    try {
        tripModel = MPtable.myModel(Parser.parsa_tratta(Database.doRequest("SELECT * from tratte")));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Mainpage2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    initComponents();
}
....
jTable1.setModel(tripModel);
....
public void tripRepaint() throws MalformedURLException, Exception{
        System.out.println(jTable1.getModel());
        tripModel = MPtable.myModel(Parser.parsa_tratta(Database.doRequest("SELECT * from tratte")));
        jTable1.setModel(tripModel);
        jTable1.repaint();

        System.out.println(jTable1.getModel());
        System.out.println(tripModel);
```

These last 3 println() show that model has changed!
    lol{}
Output:

Tratta AGGIUNTA

javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel@1ca7e4a

BOLOGNA

...

CATANZARO

NEW_DEPARTURE_ADDED

javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel@17d54dd

javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel@17d54dd

So it works..but It doesn't show new model!!

AddTrip.java http://pastebin.com/t0LqF91a

```java
Carpooling2.mainPage2.tripRepaint();
```

MPTable.java http://pastebin.com/2gXvYNLC

```java
 public class MPtable {


public static DefaultTableModel myModel(Tratta[] tratta_array){
    int i;

    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    model.addColumn("ID");
    model.addColumn("LUOGO PARTENZA");
    model.addColumn("LUOGO ARRIVO");
    model.addColumn("DATA");
    model.addColumn("ORA PARTENZA");
    model.addColumn("ORA ARRIVO");
    model.addColumn("COSTO (€)");
    model.addColumn("POSTI DISPONIBILI");
    model.addColumn("AUTISTA");
    model.addColumn("INFORMAZIONI");

    for (i=0; i<tratta_array.length; i++){
            System.out.println(tratta_array[i].getLuogoPartenza());
            }

    for (i=0; i<tratta_array.length; i++){
        model.addRow(new Object[] {
                tratta_array[i].getId(),
                tratta_array[i].getLuogoPartenza(),
                tratta_array[i].getLuogoArrivo(),
                tratta_array[i].getData(),
                tratta_array[i].getOraPartenza(),
                tratta_array[i].getOraArrivo(),
                tratta_array[i].getCosto(),
                tratta_array[i].getPostiDisponibili(),
                tratta_array[i].getAutista(),
                tratta_array[i].getInfo()
                }
        );
    }
    return model;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to inform the table, that the structure and/or data has changed. Question is answered here e.g: [JTable How to refresh table model after insert delete or update the data.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179136/jtable-how-to-refresh-table-model-after-insert-delete-or-update-the-data)

Comment: I've red it, but I've tried to add that after MPTable.myModel() or jTable1.setModel or .repaint() [all in tripRepaint()] with no success