# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 - Java SQL

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am getting the "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" but I couldn't seem to fix it. I tried changing the quotation marks and data type but still no luck. Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(!textField.getText().isEmpty() && !textField_1.getText().isEmpty() && !textField_2.getText().isEmpty() && !textField_3.getText().isEmpty() && !textField_4.getText().isEmpty() && !textField_5.getText().isEmpty() && !textField_6.getText().isEmpty() && !textField_7.getText().isEmpty())
            {
                String moduleName = textField.getText();
                String studId = textField_1.getText();
                String sFName = textField_2.getText();
                String sLName = textField_3.getText();
                int weekNo = Integer.parseInt(textField_4.getText());
                int lAttend = Integer.parseInt(textField_5.getText());
                int tAttend = Integer.parseInt(textField_6.getText());
                int wAttend = Integer.parseInt(textField_7.getText());

                lh.addStud(moduleName, studId, sFName, sLName , weekNo, lAttend, tAttend, wAttend);
            }
            else
            {
                lblNewLabel_4.setText("You have Missing Field");
            }
            fillDB();
           }
        });
```

Below is my query:

```
String aSQuery = "INSERT INTO Group6_Register VALUES ('" + moduleName + "', '" + studId + "', '" + sFName + "', '" +  sLName +"', '" +  weekNo + "', '" +  lAttend + "', '"  + tAttend + "', '" + wAttend + "')";
            statements = connection.prepareStatement(aSQuery);
            statements.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I guess `PK` field of `Group6_Register` is omitted here

Comment: where is `prepareStatement` here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

usually occurs when your columns defined in the values clause  don't match your actual table columns.

say your table have 4 coulmns, **col1 col2 col3 col4**

now you want to only insert data into **col2, col3, col4**

your insert statement should be

```
Insert into table (col2, col3, col4) values(col2val, col3val, col3val)
```

However, i would **strongly** recommend you to use [**PreparedStatement**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) while **executing sql queries using JDBC**.

```
   String query= "Insert into table (col2, col3, col4) Values(?,?,?)";
   Statement st = conn.preparedStatement(query);
   st.setString(1, col2value);
   st.setString(2, col3Val); 
   st.setString(3, col4Val);
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Very clear and helpful. One last thing, how can I refresh the JTable once I have inserted new data? I had to re-run it to see the update.

Comment: @user1781232 check thi slink http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179136/jtable-how-to-refresh-table-model-after-insert-delete-or-update-the-data

Comment: When I put tableModel.fireTableDataChanged(); I get an error saying "Syntax error on token "fireTableDataChanged", Identifier expected after this token"

Comment: I would recommend you to first work it out yourself, if you can't figure it out post as a new question for help. But I am sure you can figure it out urself :)

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are using the *implicit* type of `INSERT` statements. The server is expecting that you have provided all values for all columns but you don't that's why it threw an exception.

The best way to do is to explicitly declare the column name for which the values are bound to, ex.

```
INSERT INTO tableName (colA, colB, colC)
VALUES ('a','b','c')
```

you can only use this type of syntax when you have *all* specified values for all columns, for instance, you have a table which has *3 columns*, you can then use this

```
INSERT INTO tableName  VALUES ('a','b','c')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define the columns you insert explicitly

```
INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,coln) VALUES ( val1, val2, val3 )
```

Otherwise you have to set a value for each field