# Refresh the JTable on updating the data

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Below is my code:-

```
public class MainScreen extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter;

    public MainScreen() {
        initComponents();
        this.setSize(java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());

        sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(tblCustomer.getModel());
        tblCustomer.setRowSorter(sorter);
        List<BasicDetailsDTO> findAll = UtilDAO.getDaoBasicDetails().findAll();
        System.out.println("I'm here  "+findAll.size());


        ((DefaultTableModel) tblCustomer.getModel()).setDataVector(getDataVector(findAll), getVectorHeader());
        tblCustomer.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        tblCustomer.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(0);
        tblCustomer.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(0);

    }

    public static Vector getDataVector(List<BasicDetailsDTO> listData) {
        Vector dataVector = new Vector();
        for (BasicDetailsDTO instance : listData) {
            Vector row = new Vector();
            row.add(instance.getId());
            row.add(instance.getParticulars());
            row.add(instance.getBookedBy());
            row.add(instance.getContactPerson());
            row.add(instance.getMobileNo());
            row.add(instance.getEmail_id());
            dataVector.add(row);

        }
        return dataVector;

    }

    public static Vector getVectorHeader() {

        Vector header = new Vector();
        header.add("ID");
        header.add("Particulars");
        header.add("BOOKED BY");
        header.add("CONTACT PERSON");
        header.add("MOBILE NO");
        header.add("EMAIL ID");
        return header;

    }

    private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        displayPanel(new HomePage(), "Details Of Customer", 1200, 800);
    }                                      

    private void tblCustomerKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                      

    private void tblCustomerMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void btnDeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        if (tblCustomer.getSelectedRow() == -1) {
            displayError("Please Select the Record");
            return;
        }

        int option = displayConfirmDialog("Do you Really want to delete Record ?");
        if (option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            String recordId = tblCustomer.getValueAt(tblCustomer.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
            BasicDetailsDTO instance = UtilDAO.getDaoBasicDetails().findById(Integer.parseInt(recordId));

            instance.setDeleted(Boolean.TRUE);
            UtilDAO.getDaoBasicDetails().remove(instance);

            List<BasicDetailsDTO> findAll = UtilDAO.getDaoBasicDetails().findAll();
            getDataVector(findAll);

            displayMessage(" Record Deleted ");
        }

    }                                         

    private void btnEditActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        if (tblCustomer.getSelectedRow() == -1) {
            displayError("Please select record.");
            return;
        }
        String recordID = tblCustomer.getValueAt(tblCustomer.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
        BasicDetailsDTO instance = UtilDAO.getDaoBasicDetails().findById(Integer.parseInt(recordID));

        displayPanel(new HomePage(instance, 1), "Customer " + instance.getBillingName(), 1200, 1000);



    }                                       

    private void tblCustomerMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
            String recordID = tblCustomer.getValueAt(tblCustomer.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
            BasicDetailsDTO instance = UtilDAO.getDaoBasicDetails().findById(Integer.parseInt(recordID));

            displayPanel(new HomePage(instance, 1), "Customer " + instance.getBillingName(), 1000, 1000);
        }
    }                                        

    private void btnViewHotelListActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        displayPanel(new ViewHotelDetails(), "List Of Hotels", 800, 700);
    }                                                

    private void btnViewAgencyListActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        displayPanel(new ViewAgencyDetails(), "List Of Hotels", 800, 700);
    }                                                 

    private void txtSearchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if (evt.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_ENTER && evt.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            if (txtSearch.getText().trim().length() > 0) {
                RowFilter<TableModel, Object> filter = new RowFilter<TableModel, Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean include(javax.swing.RowFilter.Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Object> entry) {
                        String search = txtSearch.getText().trim().toLowerCase();
                        //   System.out.println(entry.getStringValue(1));
                        return (entry.getValue(1).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) != -1 || entry.getValue(2).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) != -1 || entry.getValue(3).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) != -1);
                    }
                };
                sorter.setRowFilter(filter);
                //sorter.setRowFilter(null);
                tblCustomer.setRowSorter(sorter);
                // System.out.println("New Row is " + filter);
            } else {
                sorter.setRowFilter(null);
                tblCustomer.setRowSorter(sorter);
            }
        } else {
            if (tblCustomer.getRowCount() > 0) {
                tblCustomer.requestFocus();
                tblCustomer.setRowSelectionInterval(0, 0);
            } else {
                txtSearch.requestFocus();
            }

        }
    }                                     

    private void btnInvoiceActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try {
            InputStream in = MainScreen.class.getResourceAsStream("Passenger_Name.docx");
            IXDocReport report = XDocReportRegistry.getRegistry().loadReport(in, TemplateEngineKind.Velocity);

            IContext context = report.createContext();
            if (tblCustomer.getSelectedRow() == -1) {
                displayError("Please select record.");
                return;
            }
            String recordID = tblCustomer.getValueAt(tblCustomer.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
            BasicDetailsDTO instance = UtilDAO.getDaoBasicDetails().findById(Integer.parseInt(recordID));
            context.put("Customer", instance);



            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("Passenger Name_Out.docx"));
            report.process(context, out);
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            File f = new File("Passenger Name_Out.docx");
            desktop.open(f);


        } catch (IOException | XDocReportException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }                                          

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.texture.TextureLookAndFeel");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MainScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MainScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MainScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MainScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                new MainScreen().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

    public static void setlblMessageDetail(String msg) {

        MainScreen.lblMessage.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        MainScreen.lblMessage.setText(msg);
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
}
```

Whenever I update the data within the table, the updated data is not reflected. The updated data is reflected only when I reopen the window.
Kindly help me through.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where you add your changes in the table's model?

Comment: visit this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179136/jtable-how-to-refresh-table-model-after-insert-delete-or-update-the-data) this question is already asked

Comment: `DefaultTableModel` does this automatically. Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that focuses on the problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. why voids for `DefaultTableModel` and `JTableHeader` are static
2. remove rows from `DefaultTableModel`
3. use `DocumentListener` instead of `KeyListener` for `RowFilter`
4. why is there initialized two different `LookAndFeel`s
5. updates to `DefaultTableModel` must be done on EDT, more in Oracle tutorial [Concurrency in Swing - The Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
6. search for `ResultSetTableModel`, `TableFromDatabase`, `BeanTableModel`
7. rest of issue is hidden in shadowing void or classes, note remove all static declare, there should be static only main class