# How can I use a JTable to display dynamic a list of data

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm quite new in Java, so please don't be so hard if this question is very stupid.

I have a problem. I want to display incoming messages in a list. So I choose a JTable, with an AbstractTableModel and a static LinkedList.

The initialization of the Table looks like this:

```
jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
jTable1.setModel(new MessagesTableModel());
jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
```

My AbstractTableModel looks like this:

```
public class MessagesTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
private static List<MsgGeneral> data;
// Specify the types of columns. -> constructor
Class[] types;
private static String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {
    "Timestamp",
    "Length",
    "Direction",
    "Header",
    "Content"
};

public MessagesTableModel() {
    //define column types
    types = this.types = new Class[]{
        String.class,
        Integer.class,
        String.class,
        Integer.class,
        Object.class};

    data = MainThread.MessageListGeneral;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return COLUMN_NAMES[column];
}

@Override
public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    return types[columnIndex];
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return types.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

    MsgGeneral msg = data.get(rowIndex);

    switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return msg.getTimestamp();
        case 1:
            return msg.getMsgLenght();
        case 2:
            return msg.getDirection();
        case 3:
            return msg.getHeader();
        case 4:
            return msg.getContent().toString();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

The List is simply defined like this:

```
public static LinkedList<MsgGeneral> MessageListGeneral = new LinkedList<MsgGeneral>();
```

And I fill this list like this:

```
MessageListGeneral.add(new MsgGeneral(data.length, 0, header, "some note", data));
```

And now my Question, or what I don't understand:
How can I dynamically refresh the table, when a new row is added? I think I need something like a ObservableCollection in .NET, or a event listener on the "add". How can I do that.

Thanks a lot for every hint
br Alex

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179136/jtable-how-to-refresh-table-model-after-insert-delete-or-update-the-data

Comment: I would strongly recommend Glazed Lists for this type of problem, it takes care of a LOT of the work for you and provides a thread-safe way to do this really quite easily. http://www.glazedlists.com/documentation/tutorial

Answer (score 4):

When you call `MessageListGeneral.add` it needs to fire some kind of notification, telling registered listeners that a new message is available.

These listeners then need to react to that event appropriatly.  In your case, you would need to determine the row(s) that were added and use [`fireTableRowsInserted`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsInserted%28int,%20int%29), which will notify the `JTable` that it should repaint.

This is a basic [observer pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html)