# JTable runtime error

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have set a `JTable` to initialize at the beginning of the program, and I set it to a `DefaultTableModel`:

```
public DefaultTableModel usernameScraperTableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
private JTable usernameScraperTable;
```

I then initialize the table inside the constructor as below,

```
this.usernameScraperTable = new JTable(this.usernameScraperTableModel);
this.usernameScraperTableModel.addColumn("Username");
```

and then in my `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` for my `startButton`, I run a method. If something is collected, it is supposed to add it to the table.

```
this.usernameScraperTableModel.addRow(new Object[] { user.getName() } );
```

It works somewhat. During run-time, the table is blank and doesn't show anything. I know this because in my Eclipse console it's working like it's supposed to. But after the method is done running, it then has the `JTable` update and all of the names are there.

I'm wondering how I can have my table update in real time *inside* of an `ActionEvent` of a button.

---

**EDIT**

Thanks for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22973048/2587435). It still doesn't work though. I used WindowBuilder from the Eclipse website, and it's a JFrame. When I click start, the GUI kind of "freezes" (I can't click anything else, can't press the exit button, anything) until the method is done with

Comment: possible duplicate of [JTable How to refresh table model after insert delete or update the data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179136/jtable-how-to-refresh-table-model-after-insert-delete-or-update-the-data)

Comment: `addRow` should do the trick. You need to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better help.

Comment: It sounds like some process is blocking the Event Dispatching Process from been allowed to continue processing events (including paint events).  Until the `actionPerformed` method exists, nothing can be updated.  The question then is, what are you doing in you `actionPerformed` method?

Answer (score 0):

So I believe you want the method `fireTableDataChanged()` which is part of `DefaultTableModel`, which is `usernameScraperTableModel` in your case

Comment: Thanks for this. It still doesn't work though. I used WindowBuilder from the Eclipse website, and it's a JFrame. When I click start, the GUI kind of "freezes" (I can't click anything else, can't press the exit button, anything) until the method is done with.

Comment: not all those notifiers are implemented in DefaultTableModel, usage of fireTableDataChanged() indicating concurency or EDT issue