# Select Value of Checkbox JTable on button click

Tags: java, jtable

I have a JTable in which the last column is `Checkbox(multiple select)`. I want to get the values of the rows selected on a particular button click. Only the values which are checked are needed. Any idea regarding this?

```
Object[] columnNamesTest = {"Request No","Assigned To","Copy Data","Updated Req Number"};
        Object[][] rowDataTest = {
            {"111111", "ABC",false,""},
            {"222222", "XYZ", true,"999999"},
            {"333333", "LMN",true,"444444"},
            {"444444", "PQR", false,"555555"}
        };
     DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rowDataTest, columnNamesTest);
     JTable table = new JTable(model){
         private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
          @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                switch (column) {
                    case 0:
                        return String.class;
                    case 1:
                        return String.class;
                    case 2:
                        return Boolean.class;
                    default:
                        return String.class;
                }
            }
             @Override
               public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                   //Only the third column
                   return column == 2;
               }

     }; 

    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    scrollPane.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    container.add(scrollPane);
```

Comment: Maybe you can add an handler when a checkbox is selected and for each selected item you can create a list that you can display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the values of the rows selected on a particular button click.Only the values which are checked are needed.

Simply check the value of third column and get it the desired value from `DefaultTableModel`.

sample code:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Show selcted records");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
            Boolean value = (Boolean) model.getValueAt(i, 2);// check state
            if (value) {
                System.out.println(model.getValueAt(i, 1));// second column value
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey Thanks,that worked.One more question i wanted to ask.Once i perform some action (updating some value in db from which the data in Jtable is fetched).how can i refresh the page to show the updated table

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179136/jtable-how-to-refresh-table-model-after-insert-delete-or-update-the-data) will answer your question.