# Java, Swing - Jtable row remain after delete

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I have a JTable that displays data from mysql, the code below is works (can insert, update, delete) But if I delete a row and create another with the same id, the previous data in the row (before I delete it) appears instead of new data.

code for insert and delete

```
private void simpanBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        String hantaranID = hantaranIDText.getText();
        String namaLengkap = namaLengkapET.getText();
        String alamat = jTextArea1.getText();
        String hp = noHp.getText();

        Date pengambilan = jXDatePicker1.getDate();
        Date pengembalian = jXDatePicker2.getDate();

        if (hantaranID.isEmpty()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hantaran ID tidak boleh kosong.");
        } else if (namaLengkap.isEmpty()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nama lengkap tidak boleh kosong.");
        } else if (alamat.isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Alamat tidak boleh kosong.");
        } else if (hp.isEmpty()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nomor Hand Phone tidak boleh kosong.");
        } else if (pengambilan != null && pengembalian != null){

            try {
                DateFormat sysDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
                String tglPengambilan = sysDate.format(jXDatePicker1.getDate()).toString();
                String tglPengembalian = sysDate.format(jXDatePicker2.getDate()).toString();
                Connection conn = MyDBConnection.getConnection();
                String insert = "insert into hantaran (hantaran_id, nama_lengkap, alamat, no_hp, tgl_pengambilan, tgl_pengembalian)"
                        + "values (?, ?, ? , ? , ?, ?)";
                PreparedStatement insertHantaran = conn.prepareStatement(insert, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                insertHantaran.setString(1, hantaranID);
                insertHantaran.setString(2, namaLengkap);
                insertHantaran.setString(3, alamat);
                insertHantaran.setString(4, hp);
                insertHantaran.setString(5, tglPengambilan);
                insertHantaran.setString(6, tglPengembalian);
                insertHantaran.executeUpdate();

                hantaranTabel.revalidate();
                hantaranList.clear();
                hantaranList.addAll( hantaranQuery.getResultList());

                hantaranIDText.setText("");
                namaLengkapET.setText("");
                jTextArea1.setText("");
                noHp.setText("");
                jXDatePicker1.setDate(null);
                jXDatePicker2.setDate(null);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tanggal Pengambilan dan Pengembalian tidak boleh kosong.");

        }


        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    private void hapusBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        String id = hantaranIDText.getText();

        Object[] options = { "YA", "Tidak" };
        int choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                                           "Hapus data ini??", 
                                           "Hapus..!",
                                           JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                           JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
                                           null, 
                                           options, 
                                           options[0]); 
        if (choice == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            try {
                Connection conn = MyDBConnection.getConnection();
                String reqq = "DELETE FROM hantaran WHERE hantaran_id = ?";
                PreparedStatement delete = conn.prepareStatement(reqq);
                delete.setString(1, id);
                delete.executeUpdate();

                hantaranTabel.revalidate();
                hantaranList.clear();
                hantaranList.addAll( hantaranQuery.getResultList());

                editBtn.setText("EDIT");
                hantaranIDText.setText("");
                namaLengkapET.setText("");
                jTextArea1.setText("");
                noHp.setText("");
                jXDatePicker1.setDate(null);
                jXDatePicker2.setDate(null);

                hapusBtn.setEnabled(false);
                simpanBtn.setEnabled(true);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(HennaPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

my class

```
package aplikasi_mahar;

import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "hantaran", catalog = "mahardb", schema = "")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Hantaran.findAll", query = "SELECT h FROM Hantaran h"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Hantaran.findByHantaranId", query = "SELECT h FROM Hantaran h WHERE h.hantaranId = :hantaranId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Hantaran.findByNamaLengkap", query = "SELECT h FROM Hantaran h WHERE h.namaLengkap = :namaLengkap"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Hantaran.findByAlamat", query = "SELECT h FROM Hantaran h WHERE h.alamat = :alamat"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Hantaran.findByNoHp", query = "SELECT h FROM Hantaran h WHERE h.noHp = :noHp"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Hantaran.findByTglPengambilan", query = "SELECT h FROM Hantaran h WHERE h.tglPengambilan = :tglPengambilan"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Hantaran.findByTglPengembalian", query = "SELECT h FROM Hantaran h WHERE h.tglPengembalian = :tglPengembalian")})
public class Hantaran implements Serializable {
    @Transient
    private PropertyChangeSupport changeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "hantaran_id")
    private Integer hantaranId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "nama_lengkap")
    private String namaLengkap;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "alamat")
    private String alamat;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "no_hp")
    private String noHp;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "tgl_pengambilan")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date tglPengambilan;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "tgl_pengembalian")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date tglPengembalian;

    public Hantaran() {
    }

    public Hantaran(Integer hantaranId) {
        this.hantaranId = hantaranId;
    }

    public Hantaran(Integer hantaranId, String namaLengkap, String alamat, String noHp, Date tglPengambilan, Date tglPengembalian) {
        this.hantaranId = hantaranId;
        this.namaLengkap = namaLengkap;
        this.alamat = alamat;
        this.noHp = noHp;
        this.tglPengambilan = tglPengambilan;
        this.tglPengembalian = tglPengembalian;
    }

    public Integer getHantaranId() {
        return hantaranId;
    }

    public void setHantaranId(Integer hantaranId) {
        Integer oldHantaranId = this.hantaranId;
        this.hantaranId = hantaranId;
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange("hantaranId", oldHantaranId, hantaranId);
    }

    public String getNamaLengkap() {
        return namaLengkap;
    }

    public void setNamaLengkap(String namaLengkap) {
        String oldNamaLengkap = this.namaLengkap;
        this.namaLengkap = namaLengkap;
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange("namaLengkap", oldNamaLengkap, namaLengkap);
    }

    public String getAlamat() {
        return alamat;
    }

    public void setAlamat(String alamat) {
        String oldAlamat = this.alamat;
        this.alamat = alamat;
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange("alamat", oldAlamat, alamat);
    }

    public String getNoHp() {
        return noHp;
    }

    public void setNoHp(String noHp) {
        String oldNoHp = this.noHp;
        this.noHp = noHp;
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange("noHp", oldNoHp, noHp);
    }

    public Date getTglPengambilan() {
        return tglPengambilan;
    }

    public void setTglPengambilan(Date tglPengambilan) {
        Date oldTglPengambilan = this.tglPengambilan;
        this.tglPengambilan = tglPengambilan;
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange("tglPengambilan", oldTglPengambilan, tglPengambilan);
    }

    public Date getTglPengembalian() {
        return tglPengembalian;
    }

    public void setTglPengembalian(Date tglPengembalian) {
        Date oldTglPengembalian = this.tglPengembalian;
        this.tglPengembalian = tglPengembalian;
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange("tglPengembalian", oldTglPengembalian, tglPengembalian);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (hantaranId != null ? hantaranId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Hantaran)) {
            return false;
        }
        Hantaran other = (Hantaran) object;
        if ((this.hantaranId == null && other.hantaranId != null) || (this.hantaranId != null && !this.hantaranId.equals(other.hantaranId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "aplikasi_mahar.Hantaran[ hantaranId=" + hantaranId + " ]";
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        changeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        changeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

}
```

connection class

```
public class MyDBConnection {

    static private Connection  connection;

    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception{
        if(connection == null){
            //JDBC
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mahardb", "root", "");
        }
        return connection;
    }

}
```

Notes : i'm using persistent connection, java jdk7

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code some data to replace the DB.

Comment: see below link its help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179136/jtable-how-to-refresh-table-model-after-insert-delete-or-update-the-data

Answer (score 0):

You have to set new Data for your TableModel or remove deleted Data/Row from TableModel and call ***fireTableDataChanged*** method:

```
yourTableModel.setData(getYourData());
yourTableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
```