# Removing row from java (netbeans) connected to database

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Im trying to remove row from java connected to database using this code

```
String sql="delete from buku where kode_buku=?";
int viewIndex = tabelDaftarBuku.getSelectedRow();

if(viewIndex != -1) 
{
    int modelIndex = tabelDaftarBuku.convertRowIndexToModel(viewIndex); 
    DefaultTableModel model2 = (DefaultTableModel)tabelDaftarBuku.getModel();
    model2.removeRow(modelIndex);
}

try {
    PreparedStatement pst=koneksi.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, jTKode1.getText());
    pst.execute();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deleted");
} catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
}
```

The row is deleted when i check in the database but the java table stays the same and does not update unless i re-open it. Been trying to try to solve this but still has no idea, please help...

Comment: try calling `model2.fireTableDataChanged()` after the call to `removeRow`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179136/jtable-how-to-refresh-table-model-after-insert-delete-or-update-the-data

Comment: tried it, still not updating the table

Comment: try to call `validate()` on the table's container.

Comment: either `viewIndex == -1` or the `convertRowIndexToModel` method doesn't return the correct index.

Comment: BTW: what is jTKode1?

Comment: @MauricePerry it was jText something, changed the variable name to something similar to my native language so it's easy to remember.